# Proof on Connectedness

Tags: general-topology

it holds that $X=\prod X_i$ is connected if all the $X_i$ are for an arbitrary index set. Could you check the following proof? I thinks it's wrong, but I can't find any error:

Let $X_i$ be connected for all $i$. Now assume $X$ is not connected, i. e. there exist non-zero $U,V$ open in $X$ such that X is the disjoint union of $U,V$. Hence there is an $i_0$ such that $U_{i_0}, V_{i_0}$ in the cartesion products $U$ and $V$ respectivelty such that $U_{i_0}\cap V_{i_0}=\emptyset$ and $U_{i_0}\cup V_{i_0}=X_{i_0}$ contradicting that $X_{i_0}$ is connected.

Is this proof ok?

Comment: Are $U_{i_0}$, $V_{i_0}$ open in $X_{i_0}$? Nonempty? Why would this be true of just some $i_0$ and not all $i$?

Comment: $U$ and $V$ need not be Cartesian products of open subsets of the $X_i$'s. Consider the open ball in $\Bbb R^3$, for example

Comment: Thank you Brian and Alex for your help! I see the problem in the proof now.

Comment: There is a proof in Engelking,General Topology, chapter 6. You will see it's not quite so simple.

Comment: But the projection maps are *open*: the images of open sets in the product are open in the factors.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. It confuses me: Let $U_1\times U_2 \times U_3$ a composition of the open ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is open in the product. Then each $U_i$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, because the projections are open. Thus the open ball is a cartesian product of open subsets of the $X_i=\mathbb{R}$, hence not a conterexample?!

Comment: Hey, considering Brians comment, the $U_{i_0},V_{i_0}$ are indeed open in the factors. Hence I still dont see a reason why my proof fails. Help appreciated :)